# How to reset transform.Rotate position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to, at the click of the left mouse button, rotate an object to (15,0,0), then, rotate it back to (0,0,0) after about a second.

The problem is, it doesn't rotate back and I can't seem to get it to.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HitScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool ifswung;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ifswung = false;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (ifswung == false)        
            {
            transform.Rotate(15, 0, 0);
            ifswung = true;
              }
            else if(ifswung == true)
            {
                transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
                ifswung = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ifswung = false` by default, no need for constructor. No need to check for both values of `bool`: if it's not `false`, then it's `true`. Have you tried to use `Rotate(-15,0,0)` to rotate *back*?

Comment: Very helpful. This worked although the object rotates back to -15 really quickly. Do you know any way to make it pause before rotating to (-15,0,0)?

Comment: You could use coroutines for this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Comment: hi Cyanide.  learn about `Invoke` in the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HitScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3[] rotations = { new Vextor3(15f,0f,0f),Vector3.zero } ;
    private in index = 0;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if(++index >= rotations.Length)index = 0;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotations[index]);
        }
    }
    //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,
      //                      Quaternion.Euler(rotations[index]), Time.deltaTime);
}
```

So you have two rotations stored in the array. You could also use a boolean, using the array makes it over two lines.

So each time you press the button, the index is increased and if the index is above the lengt of the array then it gets back to 0.

The last line is if you want to move slowly from one rotation to the other. You would have to comment out the one in the if statement.

Comment: you know, IMHO I believe for pedagogical reasons it's better to point hobbyist programmers to `transform.eulerAngles` and "never mention" quaternions.